Why can't see jaeger collector and query after create a jaeger instance with jaeger-operator helm chart?
I installed Jaeger Operator with helm chart as
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.15.1/cert-manager.yaml
helm install my-release jaegertracing/jaeger-operator -n observability

cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: jaegertracing.io/v1
kind: Jaeger
metadata:
  name: simplest
EOF

But when I check the services, I can see nothing about jaeger.
kubectl get svc
(NULL)

However, if I installed Jaeger Operator from source:
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.15.1/cert-manager.yaml
kubectl create -f https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-operator/releases/download/v1.62.0/jaeger-operator.yaml -n observability

cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: jaegertracing.io/v1
kind: Jaeger
metadata:
  name: simplest
EOF

I can see the jaeger collector and query:
kubectl get svc
NAME                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                                                              AGE
simplest-collector              ClusterIP      10.43.109.221   <none>         9411/TCP,14250/TCP,14267/TCP,14268/TCP,14269/TCP,4317/TCP,4318/TCP   1h
simplest-collector-headless     ClusterIP      None            <none>         9411/TCP,14250/TCP,14267/TCP,14268/TCP,14269/TCP,4317/TCP,4318/TCP   1h
simplest-query                  ClusterIP      10.43.120.122   <none>         16686/TCP,16685/TCP,16687/TCP                                        1h

Why?
